# JQuery Toggle adding # after URL, e.preventDefault(); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an issue where on IE, a # is being added to the end of the URL, after clicking on a toggle. (i.e. website.com/direc/main.html**#**

This is disabling all the toggle functions. Haven't been able to duplicate the issue on FireFox. I have an e.preventDefault(); in each function but I have not been able to resolve this issue by putting e.prevent in different locations.

Code Below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#1_EH").click(function(e){ 
        $("#1_S").slideToggle("slow");
e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#2_EH").click(function(e){ 
        $("#2_S").slideToggle("slow"); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
     });

<a href="#" id="1_EH"><img src="pic.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
<div class="client_box" id="1_S">
    <h2>text</h2>
    <p>text<a href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank">Directions &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is point of  href="#" in the <a href="#" id="1_EH"> tag?

Comment: the # is just a place holder for the reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs can't start with digits; the result is undefined and (presumably) broken in Internet Explorer. Fix your ID attributes (`1_EH`/`1_S`/etc) to start with a letter instead of a digit.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, that was the issue

Answer (score 1):

e.preventDefault() should be the first line following function(e):

```
   $("#2_EH").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
    ...stuff to be done...
    });
```

Example code fixed here: http://jsbin.com/welcome/54005/

**Not removing, however, please note that from the poster of the correct answer, this answer is Factually incorrect and should be disregarded.**

Comment: No it shouldn't, it doesn't matter where `e.preventDefault` appears so long as your function doesn't return before that line is reached. This is factually incorrect, you're spreading false information and it won't help.

Comment: I had just finished voting up your answer when I realized that I missed the id starting with a number. I apologize for the "false information", and will be more watchful in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the hash tag from the href in your link(s).